# Adding an Observable Property to a mapped Observable Array using Knockout JS Mapping Options

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am binding a table in a view using a Knockout observable array (`self.data`) which is populated by an AJAX call and the Knockout Mapping plugin. The aim is to have the ViewModel as a reusable component.

I need to add in a column to select table rows.  I want to do this by adding a boolean `isSelected` observable property to each item in the `self.data` observable array using mapping options. This observable property is then used by the `self.selectClicked` function to push or pop items to the `self.selectedItems` observable array.

Problem is, I'm not quite sure how to add the `isSelected` property to each array item.

Here is the code at the moment:

```
//// NOTE: ko.applyBindings and the AJAX call currently happen outside of this code.

function ViewModel() {

var self = this;

var mapping = {
    // Boolean observable property for each array item added here?
};

self.data = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);

self.selectClicked = function (data, event) {

    if (event.currentTarget.checked) {
        self.selectedItems.push(data);                       
    }
    else {
        self.selectedItems.pop(data);
    }

    return true;
};

// AJAX Data is pushed to the self.data observable array through this function
self.addData = function (_data) {

    ko.mapping.fromJS(_data, mapping, self.data);

};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually create the data objects and add `isSelected` using `create`:

```
var mapping = 
{
    create: function(_data) {
        return new Data(_data.data);
    }
};

self.addData = function (_data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(_data, mapping, self.data);
};

var Data = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
};
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcpvr3kt/3/)

This is documented in the [Knockout mapping plugin documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing-object-construction-using-create).

Comment: I suspect I have done something wrong somewhere, but I'm getting a `ReferenceError: Name is not defined` error from Knockout (Name is the first column of the table). I can't see why the solution would be incorrect, but replacing the mapping parameter in `ko.mapping.fromJS(_data, mapping, self.data);` with `{}` doesn't cause an issue, so it seems the problem is with the mapping call ('ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self)') in 'Data'.

Comment: So Name is coming back from the server? Check the network tab?

Comment: The Ajax data is coming back fine, just get the error when including the mapping.

Comment: There was a problem with my mapping `create` function. To get the data, you need to use `_data.data`. I updated my answer